# Use moment.js to insert date inside HTML5 <time> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetime, momentjs

I want to use moment.js to insert a backdated `RFC 3339` timestamp inside an HTML5 `<time>` tag, so it renders into the HTML this:

`<time datetime="2016-01-14T13:22:11-08:00">Lorem Ipsum</time>`

With moment.js, my .js is working correctly to generate the timestamp:

`document.getElementById('fourDaysEarlier').innerHTML = moment().subtract(4, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ")`

which I can successfully write into the document with `innerHTML` like this:

`<span id="fourDaysEarlier"></span>`

But how do I insert the timestamp inside the `<time>` tag, like this??

`<time datetime="wantToInsertTimeStampHere">Lorem Ipsum</time>`

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just use vanilla javascript [setAttribute()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp) method like

```
    document.getElementById('fourDaysEarlier').setAttribute("datetime", moment().subtract(4, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ"));
```

or if you are using jQuery - [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method

```
    $('#fourDaysEarlier').attr("datetime", moment().subtract(4, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ") )
```